# The uploaded file must have a valid image format, but format was: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------749c9bf517f13444

Tags: php, google-streetview-publish

```
 <form action="i am calling another php file here" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" value="choose">
    <input type="hidden" name="upurl" value="<?php echo $upload_url;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" id="" value= <?php echo $access_token;?>>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" >
</form>




<?php
if ( isset($_FILES['fileToUpload']) ) {
    $d=$_POST;  
    $imagePath=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
    $type=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'];
    $upload_url=$d['upurl'];
    $access_token=$d['token'];
    $f=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
    $ch=curl_init();
    $cfile= curl_file_create($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    $data=array("media"=>$cfile);
    $header = array("authorization: Bearer $access_token",
     "content-type: multipart/form-data");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$upload_url);
    $response=curl_exec($ch);
    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
      if($response== true){echo "file posted";}
      else{echo"error";}
 }
?>
```

my http response here...

> Array ( [url] =>
>   https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/media/user/10367060812938697279/photo/891443328548839265
>   [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8 [http_code] => 400
>   [header_size] => 446 )

Comment: i got my answer....thank you

Answer (score -2):

The `content-type` header specifies the type and extension of the file being uploaded, here's a [list of available types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type#mime.types), it looks like you need to set it to image/jpeg